# ¿Cual es la forma correcta para guardar y obtener registros segun la fecha en un nodo de firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase

Buen día.

Actualmente me encuentro agregando registros a un nodo en firebase, dicho nodo es llamado "comunicados", que se ve de la siguiente forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como verán cada registro contiene su propiedad "fecha_creacion", en que formato debería guardar la fecha_creación utilizando javascript.

Lo estoy guardando de la siguiente forma:

```
    let fecha_actual = new Date()
    let anio = fecha_actual.getFullYear();
    let mes  = fecha_actual.getMonth();
    let dia  = fecha_actual.getDate();
    console.log("Fecha actual: ");
    console.log(fecha_actual)
 let dia_fecha = anio+mes+dia;
        console.log("DIA FECHA: ");
        console.log(dia_fecha);



firebase
.database()
.ref('comunicados')
.push({
   'titulo': 'Comunicado',
   'mensaje': 'Mensaje del comunicado'
   'fecha_creacion': dia_fecha
})
.then(()=>{
    console.log("AGREGANDO COMUNICADO");
});
```

Seguidamente estoy intentando obtener los comunicados que se hayan creado el día de hoy, mediante firebase de la siguiente forma:

```
firebase
          .database()
          .ref('comunicados')
          .orderByChild('fecha_creacion')
          .startAt(dia_fecha)
          .on('value', snapshot => this.obtenerComunicados(snapshot.val()))
```

Pero tal situación no me funciona, ya que me devuelve todos los registros.
Como sería la forma correcta para crear un comunicado mediante la fecha y luego obtener los comunicados según la fecha que se solicite.

De antemano muy agradecido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Todas las fechas que se suben a Firebase deberian estar en Timestamp, por ejemplo , el dia de hoy seria interpretado como Timestamp de la siguiente forma

```
1550678425
```

Si copias y pegas ese numero en la siguiente pagina https://www.epochconverter.com/

vas a poder ver la fecha del dia de hoy.

Al guardar las fechas de esta forma en Firebase, es mas facil ordenarlas con el `orderBy` para luego ser mostradas.

Para subir el timestamp a Firebase lo podes hacer usando la siguiente linea

```
Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
```

Firestore

```
firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
```

Para convertir este timestamp de Firebase a la fecha que desees podes hacer lo siguiente

```
db.ref("/.info/serverTimeOffset").on('value', function(offset) {
    var offsetVal = offset.val() || 0;
    var serverTime = Date.now() + offsetVal;
  });
```

`/.info` es una seccion especial en Firebase donde devuelve resultados, no hace falta que sea una referencia a tu tabla

Comment: Estimado y para luego obtener los registros según la fecha o en ese caso TIMESTAMP. Por ejemplo para obtener los registros de hoy que pertenezcan al nodo comunicados.

Comment: Traes el timestamp y lo comparas con el de hoy obteniendo lo con systemtimestamp, va a variar los segundos pero parte de todo el timestamp va a ser el mismo